# Submitted $_GET form to create pretty URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm reformatting my URLs so that `team.php?s=football` rewrites to `team/football/`, which i've managed to do using the following in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ ./team.php?s=$1
```

Now typing in `localhost/proj/team/football` loads the correct valid page.

I have a `$_GET` form on `sports.php` that submits to `team.php`, however on submission the form still creates the url `team.php?s=football`. How can I change in what format the form submits as?

The form is as follows:

```
<form id="choosesport" action="team" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="s" value=""/>
      <svg>...</svg>
</form>
```

And accompanying JS to fill in the `input` field based on the clicked SVG element:

```
function sport(name) {
    $("form#choosesport").find("input[type='hidden']").val(name);
    $("form#choosesport").submit();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#netballBtn").on('click', function() {
        sport("netball");
    });
    $("a#rugbyBtn").on('click', function() {
        sport("rugby");
    });
    $("a#badmintonBtn").on('click', function() {
        sport("badminton");
    });
    $("a#footballBtn").on('click', function() {
        sport("football");
    })
});
```

Comment: May be obvious for you but I dont know what you mean ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the field and add it to the action

```
function sport(name) {
  const $form = $("form#choosesport");
  $form.find("input[type='hidden']").remove()
  $form.attr("action",$form.attr("action")+"/"+name+"/");
  $form.submit();
}
```

Or use Ajax:

```
function sport(name) {
  const $form = $("form#choosesport");
  $("#someContainer").load($form.attr("action")+"?s="+name); // or as above
}
```

Comment: How does one reach the value of the $_GET variable this way? var_dump($_GET) returns `array (size=0) empty` - is there a cleaner way than exploding the url?

Comment: What if AJAX method is not suitable? I specifically need to redirect to the other page rather than load in

Comment: it does, however I cant use $_GET to easily access the value. I had to explode the URL at slashes, and use `array_filter` to get rid of corner case strings and take the last item as `$_GET`. chrome also appends a trailing `?` to the URL that way.

Comment: @peterxz Why are you having problems with accessing the value all of a sudden now – I thought you said you had set up your rewriting already?

Comment: I couldnt access it to begin with, I used the first example as AJAX is not suitable. var_dump($_GET) returns nothing and $_GET['s'] is also undefined. I solved it by exploding the href part of the url into groups but is not a very clean solution.